# how can i show the form with fade option on onclick button using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show form when click a button. 
I already tried this
`$('.mydiv').show(slow);`

It works fine but I need to know how to apply effect.

Comment: $('.mydiv').show(slow); this is code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want fadein effect means

```
    <script>$(.btn).click(function(){$('.mydiv').fadeIn();});</script>
```

if you want other effects then replace fadeIn with respective effects.
http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 0):

You use **[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** method, which only display the element - `div`.

```
$('.mydiv').show(slow);
```

Should Replace with **[`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)** method, which open element - `div`  by fading effect:

```
$('.mydiv').fadeIn( "slow" );
```